# Change image source depending on alt tag not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the images of a multi review system where the individual stars were never given a class or id.

Here's an example of what a star review looks like:

```
<div id="rate">
  <span class="rating_text">Bathroom Availability</span> 
  <img alt="star_rated" src="star_rated.png">
  <img alt="star_rated" src="star_rated.png">
  <img alt="star_rated" src="star_rated.png">
  <img alt="star_rated_half" src="star_rated_half.png">
  <img alt="star_normal" src="star_normal.png">
</div>
<div id="rate">
  <span class="rating_text">Course Level</span> 
  <img alt="star_rated" src="star_rated.png">
  <img alt="star_rated" src="star_rated.png">
  <img alt="star_rated" src="star_rated.png">
  <img alt="star_rated_half" src="star_rated_half.png">
  <img alt="star_normal" src="star_normal.png">
</div>
```

The goal is to have the Bathroom Availability icons look different than the course level icons, but I can't figure out how to change the images if it's not a rated star or a different image if it's half a star.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var PAF = $('.rating_text:contains("Bathroom Availability")').next('img'); 
  if (PAF).attr('alt') == "star_rated_half") {
    $( PAF ).addClass( "testif" );
  }

  $( PAF ).addClass( "myClass" );

});
```

The variable declaration works, as it pulls up the next image. I'm able to add the class "myClass", but the class testif does not appear. What exactly am I doing wrong here? What I'd like to do is change the image source, but I haven't even been able to get the if statement to work, so I've been focusing on that.

Thank's for the assistance.
Edit: I'd like for the markup to result something like this

```
<div id="rate">
  <span class="rating_text">Bathroom Availability</span> 
  <img alt="star_rated" src="bath_star.png">
  <img alt="star_rated" src="bath_star.png">
  <img alt="star_rated" src="bath_star.png">
  <img alt="star_rated_half" src="bath_star_half.png">
  <img alt="star_normal" src="bath_star_empty.png">
</div>
<div id="rate">
  <span class="rating_text">Course Level</span> 
  <img alt="star_rated" src="course_star.png">
  <img alt="star_rated" src="course_star.png">
  <img alt="star_rated" src="course_star.png">
  <img alt="star_rated_half" src="course_star_half.png">
  <img alt="star_normal" src="course_star_empty.png">
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, can you also share the result markup that you are looking for

Comment: the selector `$('PAF[alt="star_rated_half"]')` is wrong...

Comment: <div id="rate">
      <span class="rating_text">Bathroom Availability</span> 
      <img alt="star_rated" src="bathroom_star.png">
      <img alt="star_rated" src="bathroom_star.png">
      <img alt="star_rated" src="bathroom_star.png">
      <img alt="star_rated" src="bathroom_star_half.png">
      <img alt="star_rated" src="bathroom_star_empty.png">
    </div>

Comment: similar with course level but instead of bathroomm_star it'd be course_star

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var PAF = $('.rating_text:contains("Bathroom Availability")').nextAll('img'); 
  if (PAF.attr('alt') == "star_rated_half") {
    PAF.addClass( "testif" );
  }

  PAF.addClass( "myClass" );

});
```

Comment: I"m getting the "myClass" added, but I'm not getting the "testif" class added as well.

Comment: http://run.flywheelsites.com/city/memphis/listing/gibson-5k/#comment-4 If you'd like to take a look at the site, here's a link

Comment: you used next or nextAll ?

Answer (score 0):

First, ID of an element must be unique, so use `rate` as a class value instead of as an ID.

then try

```
$(function () {
    function convert(text, prefix){
        var $rate = $('.rate').has('.rating_text:contains("'+text+'")');
        $rate.find('.star_rated').attr('src', prefix+'_star.png');
        $rate.find('.star_rated_half').attr('src', prefix+'_star_half.png');
        $rate.find('.star_normal').attr('src', prefix+'_star_empty.png');
    }
    convert('Bathroom Availability', 'bathroom');
    convert('Course Level', 'cource');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/G22QV/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

html

```
<div class="rate"> <span class="rating_text">Bathroom Availability</span> 
    <img alt="star_rated" src="star_rated.png" />
    <img alt="star_rated" src="star_rated.png" />
    <img alt="star_rated" src="star_rated.png" />
    <img alt="star_rated_half" src="star_rated_half.png" />
    <img alt="star_normal" src="star_normal.png" />
</div>
<br />
<div class="rate"> <span class="rating_text">Course Level</span> 
    <img alt="star_rated" src="star_rated.png" />
    <img alt="star_rated" src="star_rated.png" />
    <img alt="star_rated" src="star_rated.png" />
    <img alt="star_rated_half" src="star_rated_half.png" />
    <img alt="star_normal" src="star_normal.png" />
</div>
```

js

```
    $(".rate *:contains(Bathroom Availability)")
    .parent()
    .find("[alt=star_rated_half]")
    .addClass("testif")
    .addBack()
    .not(".testif")
    .addClass("myClass")
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/YSU4h/